# One-liner to sort by trailing number suffix

Tags: ruby, awk

I have a series of lines with the following syntax:

```
sweets   apple:11   banana:9   cherry:101   donut:1   egg tart:86   
tossed   added:5   anted:13   ashley:3   bandied:3   flung:6   lobbed:4   salad:26   slung:9
plenty   abundance:3   a lot:83   ample:12   aroar:3   a ton:12   enow:5   gobs:5   lots:27   lotsa:8   
 
(the large spaces are all tabs)
```

Desired output is columns 2+ sorted numerically by the number after the colons. e.g.

```
sweets   cherry:101   egg tart:86   apple:11   banana:9   donut:1   
tossed   salad:26   anted:13   slung:9   flung:6   added:5   lobbed:4   ashley:3   bandied:3
plenty   a lot:83   lots:27   a ton:12   ample:12   lotsa:8   abundance:3   enow:5   gobs:5   aroar:3
```

I often use ruby one-liners..

```
//alphabetize within a line, delimited by pipes "|" 
ruby -pe '$_=$_.strip.split("|").sort().join("|")+"\n"'

//case insensitive with no dupes:
ruby -pe '$_=$_.strip.split("|").sort_by{|x| x.downcase }.uniq.join("|")+"\n"' 

//keep the first term:
ruby -pe '$_=$_.split(":")[0].strip+":"+$_.split(":")[1].strip.split("|").sort.join("|")+"\n"'
```

But I can't quite wrap my brain around a simple and clean way to sort by the trailing number. i.e. the ":NN". I'm sure this can be done with a few characters. How? I'm also happy for an awk solution, but ruby is often cleaner for more complex processing.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. Done. Expanded input/output examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
cat file
headword    apple:11    zanana:9    cherry:101  donut:1 egg tart:86
```

In Ruby, I would do:

```
ruby -F"\t" -lane  'puts $F.sort_by{ |w|  
    idx=w[/(?<=:)\d+/]
    if (idx.nil?)
        -1/0.0
    else 
        -idx.to_i
    end
}.join("\t")' file
```

Or if we *know* the first word is not to be sorted and the rest have digits, you can do:

```
ruby -F"\t" -lane 'hw, *arr = $F; puts "#{hw}\t#{arr.sort_by{ |w| -w[/(?<=:)\d+/].to_i }.join("\t")}"' file
```

Or in GNU awk, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
function byn(i1, v1, i2, v2,    l, r)
{
    if (index(v1,":")==0 || index(v2,":")==0) return -1
    split(v1,va1,/:/)
    split(v2,va2,/:/)

    if (va1[2]>va2[2])
        return -1
    else if (va1[2]==va2[2])
        return 0
    else
        return 1
}
{split($0, fields, /\t+/)
asort(fields, result, "byn")
for (i=1; i<=length(result); i++) 
    printf "%s%s", result[i], i==length(result) ? ORS : OFS}' file
```

All three print:

```
headword    cherry:101  egg tart:86 apple:11    zanana:9    donut:1
```

Comment: If we _know_ the first word always goes at the front, the logic can be a bit cleaner for not having to make sure it always stays sorted to the front. `ruby -F"\t" -lane 'hw, *arr = $f; puts "#{hw}\t#{arr.sort_by{ |w| -w[/(?<=:)\d+/].to_i }.join("\t")}"'`

Comment: @dawg nice, elegant work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` is the result of splitting each line on `\t` characters.

```
irb(main):009:0> "#{a[0]}\t#{a[1..].sort { |a, b| b.split(":")[1].to_i <=> a.split(":")[1].to_i }.join("\t")}"
=> "headword\tcherry:101\tegg tart:86\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tdonut:1"
```

Each line is split on tabs. This gives us an array:

```
["headword", "apple:11", "banana:9", "cherry:101", "donut:1", "egg tart:86"]
```

We can leave the first element alone. We can then sort the remaining elements by splitting them into key/value pairs and comparing the second element of each. If we compare `b` to `a` we get descending order.

```
ruby -pe 'a=$_.split("\t");puts "#{a[0]}\t#{a[1..].sort{|a,b|b.split(":")[1].to_i<=>a.split(":")[1].to_i}.join("\t")}"'
```

Comment: Consider `"#{a.first}\t#{a.drop(1).sort_by { |s| -s.split(":").last.to_i }.join("\t")}"`, mainly to use `sort_by`, which is more efficient than `sort` because the block calculation is performed only once for each element of `a.drop(1)`.

Comment: Definitely. Though I feel like you demonstrated that in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71638938/15261315) pretty well, and I don't want to rip you off. If I were going to, I'd probably copy the `hw, *arr = ...` you used and I was apparently still too asleep to take advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

```
> str = "headword\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tcherry:101\tdonut:1\tegg tart:86"
=> "headword\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tcherry:101\tdonut:1\tegg tart:86"
> (x = str.split("\t"))[1..-1].sort_by { |x| x.split(':')[-1].to_i }.reverse.prepend(x[0]).join("\t")
=> "headword\tcherry:101\tegg tart:86\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tdonut:1"
```

Comment: Where you have `str.split("\t")[0]` I suggest `str.split("\t", 2)[0]` to avoid unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "headword\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tcherry:101\tdonut:1\tegg tart:86"
```

```
hw, *arr = str.split("\t")
hw
  #=> "headword"
arr
  #=> ["apple:11", "banana:9", "cherry:101", "donut:1", "egg tart:86"]
```

```
[hw, *arr.sort_by { |s| -s[/(?<=:)\d+/].to_i }].join("\t")
  #=>"headword\tcherry:101\tegg tart:86\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tdonut:1"
```

Comment: Minor note: by splitting on whitespace, you've split `"egg"` and `"tart:86"` from each other. You may wish to split on either the tab mentioned by the OP or _multiple_ spaces.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the head's up. I'll fix it.

Comment: No problem. I'm much better at spotting mistakes like that in others' code than my own.

Comment: @Chris, I think it's OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
}
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,t,":")
        nums[i] = t[2]
    }
    out = $1
    for (i in nums) {
        out = out OFS $i
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
sweets  cherry:101      egg tart:86     apple:11        banana:9        donut:1
tossed  salad:26        anted:13        slung:9 flung:6 added:5 lobbed:4       bandied:3        ashley:3
plenty  a lot:83        lots:27 a ton:12        ample:12        lotsa:8 enow:5 gobs:5   aroar:3 abundance:3
```

If you really find it useful to cram it all into a "one-liner" for some reason then of course you can:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){split($i,t,":");n[i]=t[2]}o=$1;for(i in n)o=o FS $i;print o}' file
sweets  cherry:101      egg tart:86     apple:11        banana:9        donut:1
tossed  salad:26        anted:13        slung:9 flung:6 added:5 lobbed:4       bandied:3        ashley:3
plenty  a lot:83        lots:27 a ton:12        ample:12        lotsa:8 enow:5 gobs:5   aroar:3 abundance:3
```

but it loses a wee bit of clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Not a one-liner, but my take:

```rb
line = "headword\tapple:11\tbanana:9\tcherry:101\tdonut:1\tegg tart:86"
fields = line.split(/\t/)
result =  [fields[0]]
            .concat(
              fields[1..-1]
                .map {|each| each.split(":")}
                .sort {|a, b| b[1].to_i <=> a[1].to_i}
                .map {|each| each.join(":")}
            )
            .join "\t"
```